# How to manually restore Mandriva's "drakbackup" backups?

Tags: backup, mandriva

I'm currently migrating a production environment from Mandriva 2010.1 to Debian 7.0 Wheezy. The old environment used the `drakbackup` tool provided with Mandriva for hourly backups. I'm planning on using `bacula` as a more permanent and distro-agnostic solution for the Debian environment. The problem is, I need to provide continuity in terms of being able to restore the previous Mandriva backups. Usually, I could restore them easily from within `mcc` (Mandriva Control Center); however, I'm not sure how to accomplish this manually.

**What I know so far**

- Mandriva keeps lists of every archive's contents in `gzipped` text files.
- Mandriva has `gzip` archives for base and incremental backups named after their creation time.
- I can thus easily locate a certain file from the list files and extract the version I need from the base and incremental archives

**What I need to know**

- How do I merge the base and incremental backups to form the "complete" file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question turns out to be irrelevant. The name "incremental" misled me into thinking the incremental backups were actually deltas of changed files. It turns out, the incremental backups are **full copies** of the files that changed since the last backup was run.